# Do DI Containers need to instantiate the object themselves in order to use constructor injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Or instead of creating the object themselves, do they somehow *intercept* or *hook into* object creation (for example, a Controller instantiated by the MVC framework) and pass in whatever dependencies they're required to?

I realize they need to *do something* when the object is created in order to use constructor injection, but I am unclear as to whether the containers need to do the creating, or if they somehow  intercept the object's creation.

Whatever the answer is, do all DI containers do it this way?

I realize this question is probably obvious to most familiar with tools like StructureMap, Unity, Ninject, etc... but I am new to them and realized I don't really know how they work under the covers. I have scoured the internet and can't find a good answer.

Comment: In case your classes accept their dependencies through constructor arguments, it's hard to imagine that the container does not invoke the constructor, because how would it otherwise get the dependencies in and get the class correctly initialized. It is technically possible, but just calling the constructor is just so much easier, safer and faster in terms of performance.

Comment: @Steven: see my answer, the container doesn't really have to call the constructor directly.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: I read your answer and my comment can be seen as an addition to your answer. I specifically target the case where you *do* use constructor injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all the DI/IoC containers I've used, the containers do the creating themselves. You won't find any production code using `new Something(dependency1, dependency2)`... instead, you'll have code implicitly or explicitly asking the container for "an instance of `Something`" (maybe as a dependency of something else). The container then takes care of either reusing an instance of `Something`, based on how it's configured (and how `Something` is annotated).

Where you *do* often explicitly call the constructor is in the test for `Something`, at which point the container may well not exist at all - or you may have a test-specific configuration which allows you to ask for some of the dependencies in a stock way, and maybe provide other dependencies in a test-specific way. (In some cases, you *still* won't need to call the constructor explicitly... if you have a test configuration for the container, e.g. using fake storage for everything, then you may still just need to ask for an instance of `Something` to use in your tests.)

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three slightly different approaches.

A most common one is when the container calls the constructor by itself, using some kind of reflection and recursive approach to parameter resolving.

Sometimes however, existing instances (created manually) are passed to the container to **build them up** which is to satisfy these dependencies that can be satisfied otherwise than by constructor injection (otherwise here means "with property injection"). This could not be what you ask about, though.

```
 var foo = new Foo( new Bar() );
 container.BuildUp( foo );
```

The last approach that is often used is when **a factory method** is registered in the container. The container doesn't call the constructor in this approach then, rather, it calls the factory method and the method is implemented manually, which means that the factory's code calls the constructor directly:

```
 container.RegisterType<IFoo>( 
    new InjectionFactory( c => new Foo( new Bar() ) ) );
```