# "No IUserTokenProvider is registered" when using structuremap dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, structuremap

I have an MVC 5 project that has been modified to use int as the primary key for identity as shown in this [guide](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)

I then enabled email confirmation as described in [this guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

Everything worked fine as expected. Then I installed structuremap.mvc5 for dependency injection and added modified DefaultRegistry.cs to

```
public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(MyProject.Data.MyDbContext));
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });
        //For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
        For<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>>().Use<MyUserStore>().LifecycleIs<HttpContextLifecycle>();
        For<IAuthenticationManager>().Use(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);

    }
```

The project builds fine but when trying to register a new user on the site, the send email confirmation now throws an exception System.NotSupportedException: No IUserTokenProvider is registered when calling UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID).

```
private async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(int userID, string subject)
    {
        string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
           new { userId = userID, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userID, subject,
           "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

        return callbackUrl;
    }
```

I am new to dependency injection and pretty sure I am doing something wrong. I'll appreciate your thoughts and insights.

Comment: How do you have configured your `UserManager`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I was using the default definition of the UserManger which gets an instance from the owin context and didn't do any configurations. I eventually ended up doing something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240873/issues-configuring-structuremap-mvc5-to-work-with-identity but will like to know if there's a better approach as this looks more like a hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IUserTokenProvider` by default is inserted by OWIN, but when you resolve `UserManager` from your DI container, component that provides `IUserTokenProvider` is not available and this component is not initialised.

You'll have to assign token provider to a global static variable when it is available and then re-use it  in `UserManager` constructor:

```
public class AuthConfig
{
    public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

        // do other configuration 
    }
}
```

And in then re-assign it in constructor of UserManager constructor:

```
public UserManager(/*your dependecies*/)
{
    var dataProtectorProvider = AuthConfig.DataProtectionProvider;
    var dataProtector = dataProtectorProvider.Create("My Asp.Net Identity");
    this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, Guid>(dataProtector)
    {
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
    };
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is similar to what I have done so far.