# Get DataProtectionProvider in MVC 5 for dependecy injection correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, owin, owin-security

When trying to create a `DataProtectionProvider` manually I have stumbled upon the Microsoft documenation to [`DpapiDataProtectionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.dataprotection.dpapidataprotectionprovider(v=vs.113).aspx) which says:

> Used to provide the data protection services that are derived from the
>   Data Protection API. **It is the best choice of data protection when you
>   application is not hosted by ASP.NET** and all processes are running as
>   the same domain identity.

A question suddenly arises: **What is the best choice when your application IS hosted by ASP.NET?**

Searching further, it seems the best choice is to obtain the `DataProtectionProvider` from OWIN. That can be done in Startup configuration, where you have `IAppBuilder` and using `AppBuilderExtensions` located in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection` namespace you can call `app.GetDataProtectionProvider()`.

So far, I am quite satisfied. However, now you want to inject the `DataProtectionProvider` in a constructor of your class (e.g. a `UserManager`). I have seen [one suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471363/no-iusertokenprovider-is-registered-when-using-structuremap-dependency-injecti) where you store the `DataProtectionProvider` in a static property and then use it where you need, but that seems like a rather wrong solution.

I think a solution similar to the following piece of code would be appropriate (using ninject container):

```
kernel.Bind<IDataProtectionProvider>()
    // beware, method .GetDataProtectionProvider() is fictional
    .ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetDataProtectionProvider())
    .InRequestScope();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402223958/https://www.talksharp.com/configuring-autofac-to-work-with-the-aspnet-identity-framework-in-mvc-5) that tells you how to register the DataProtectionProvider with Autofac.

```
builder.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the DI container should be initialised in the startup class.

Comment: Yes, or a class that is called by the `Startup` class, as long as it is part of your composition root. Someone else asked a question about how to setup Ninject with OWIN (I can't seem to find it), and this turns out to be a major rats nest because both OWIN and Ninject want to own the starting point of the application. Considering that Ninject is also one of the slowest DI containers out there, I would personally find a different container that is easier to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this is an ongoing project, so changing ninject to something else is an option but for later.

Comment: It really seems that the only way to obtain it properly is really using the `IAppBuilder` extension.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I have updated the link to the internet archive.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this with Unity with the following line:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataProtectionProvider>(new InjectionFactory(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()));
```

Where container is

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
```

This will allow you to use the DataProtectionProvider in the constructor as follows.

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IIdentityMessageService emailService, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
```

I prefer this approach over the approach mentioned on this blog post here https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/, simply because it allows you to have the classes that use the DataProtectionProvider in separate libraries if you would like and it is much cleaner.