# Using IDataProtectionProvider in asp.net MVC 5 (not core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to do is to encrypt/decryption some sting. Is it possible to use `IDataProtectionProvider` in my ASP.NET MVC (not core) project?

I can see the interface is defined in the following packages:

1. Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection

I am not sure which one of the above packages I should use? Also, not sure how to actually instantiate *DataProtector*?

Comment: Probably the one that *doesn't* have aspnetcore in its name

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem is that I don't know where is the implementation...

Comment: This is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473209/get-dataprotectionprovider-in-mvc-5-for-dependecy-injection-correctly

Comment: Dont tag this as aspnetcore if its not for core plz

Comment: Thought the .net runtime can handle an AspNetCore package, doesnt mean it should be used with AspNet framework. They are two completely different frameworks that dont share patterns, flow and dependecy injection. I would not recommend mixing the two.

Comment: @Gekctek: what is the problem with installing ASP.NET Core packages on ASP.NET MVC? Even Microsoft's default MVC template comes with Identity.Core packages.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` is for .net core but `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` is just a convention for packages to have the 'core' library included.
There can be cases where maybe it would work but at minimum it is bad practice and can lead to unwanted behavior or errors

Answer (score 2):

This is related to this: [Get DataProtectionProvider in MVC 5 for dependecy injection correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473209/get-dataprotectionprovider-in-mvc-5-for-dependecy-injection-correctly)

and after you inject it, you can now use it in your constructor something like this:

```
public IDataProtectionProvider _iDataProtectionProvider;

public FooController(IDataProtectionProvider iDataProtectionProvider)
{
    _iDataProtectionProvider = iDataProtectionProvider
}
```