# ASP .NET Core FormsAuthentication Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, forms-authentication

I have several ASP.NET MVC 5 applications. All applications are deployed on subdomains of a common domain. A single application is responsible for user login and the session is shared among all subdomains because we have the same machineKey in all applications.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="SSO" loginUrl="{loginUrl}" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="{validationKey}" decryptionKey="{decryptionKey}" validation="SHA1" />
```

The problem is that now I want to develop new applications using ASP.NET CORE and I haven't been able to figure out how to configure the ASP.NET CORE app so that it reads auth cookie created by the ASP.NET MVC 5 application. Is it possible without making changes to ASP.NET MVC 5 applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data Protection key provider.
In the startup file configure Data protection storage like below.
In your MVC5 app also use the same storage to persist your cookie.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}")
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
});
```

Comment: But this will require modifications in existing apps as well. The .Net version of ASP.NET MVC 5 apps is 4.5 so I can't install the Data Protection package in those unless I update the version.

Comment: For. Net 4.5 it can implement along with application manager. You don't need to upgrade versions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473209/get-dataprotectionprovider-in-mvc-5-for-dependecy-injection-correctly